# Do subqueries preserve indexes

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know if the value returned from subqueries in Oracle loses indexes or not.

```
select * from emp where empid = 1
-- empid is indexed
```

```sql
select t1.* from (select t2.* from emp t2) t1 where t1.empid = 1  
-- t1.empid  is still indexed?
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking A `SELECT` query will never drop an index, if that's that you're asking. @AlexFilipovici I think it's more notable the editor didn't fix that.

Comment: Check the execution plan and you will know

Comment: @TheNewIdiot - Please format code as code, not as quote. If you format code as quote you don't get syntax highlighting and white space gets collapsed.

Comment: @BurhaKhalid I'm not sure the title you changed it to is what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the second query uses the index. In fact, both compile down to the exact same execution plan. Check it on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6aac8/1).

You should keep in mind that SQL processing is lazy: sub-queries are not necessarily fully executed to get input data to the top-level query. Instead, they should be regarded as code that can be invoked, as needed, to get that data.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the query optimisation process is to simplify the structure of the supplied query. This generally can mean replacing IN and EXISTS with joins, pushing predicates into inline views and eliminating subqueries entirely.

In fact because this behaviour is so prevalant there are a few techniques (optimiser hints, for example, or common table expressions, or certain logically redundant clauses) specifically designed to prevent predicate pushing and subquery merging and other query transformations where they are unintentionally disadvantageous.

By default you should expect that subqueries and inline views will be merged into the parent query where logically possible, and as others have mentioned this is almost certainly the case in your example.

It follows from all of this, of course, that using subqueries or inline views generally doesn't impair the optimiser's ability to use indexes or query rewrite or various other performance enhancing techniques.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer on this question: some times yes and sometimes no. It depends on many factors. In general , just not going deeply into theory, try to avoid such style of query writing to be on safe side or in other words views are bad in most of the cases. Please refer to http://www.orafaq.com/tuningguide/push%20predicates.html for more details.